# Elasticsearch cache query not working if query type is default

Tags: java, caching, elasticsearch

How to cache the query in Elasticsearch ? As per the details given in below link, we are able to cache if the querytype is COUNT and it is not working if we change the querytype(QUERY_AND_FETCH) . How to handle this ?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/index-modules-shard-query-cache.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. This is an excerpt from the link you have given.

For now, the query cache will **only** cache the results of search requests where `?search_type=count`, so it will **not cache hits**, but it will cache hits.total, aggregations, and suggestions.

Comment: Thanks :) I saw  that after posting. I think it will help others too